# Is it possible to have [Nullable[bool]] in a bool[] in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, null, tri-state-logic

Is it possible to have [Nullable[bool]] in a bool[] in PowerShell? I tried different solution, approaches but fail to get proper $null, $true, $false for a parameter? Also it seems that [cmdletbinding] changes how things works as well.

```
enum BoolNull {
    null = $null
    true = $true
    false = $false
}
function Test-Array0 {
    param (
        [bool[]] $thisValue
    )
    if ($thisValue -eq $null) {
        Write-Output 'Null found'
    }
}
function Test-Array1 {
    param (
        [bool[]] $thisValue
    )
    foreach ($value in $thisValue) {
        if ($value -eq $null) {
            Write-Output 'Null found'
        }
    }
}
function Test-Array2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [bool[]] $thisValue
    )
    if ($thisValue -eq $null) {
        Write-Output 'Null found'
    }
}


function Test-Array {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [AllowEmptyCollection()] [AllowNull()][ValidateSet($null, $true, $false)] $thisValue
    )
    if ($thisValue -eq $null) {
        Write-Output 'Null found'
    }
}

# this works
function Test-Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [nullable[bool]] $thisValue
    )
    if ($thisValue -eq $null) {
        Write-Output 'Null found'
    }
}

function Test-Array5 {
    param (
        [boolnull[]] $thisValue
    )
    foreach ($value in $thisValue) {
        if ($value -eq 'null') {
            Write-Output 'Null found'
        }
    }
}

Test-Array0 -thisValue $null #this works
Test-Array -thisValue $null # this doesn't work
Test-Array -thisValue $null, $null, $true # this doesn't work
Test-Array1 -thisValue $null
Test-Array2 -thisValue $null # this
Test-Test -thisValue $null # this works 
Test-Array5 -thisValue null, true, null # this works but is completely useless
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of the bool type.  When you strictly-type the parameter, it can only take `$true`, `$false`, `0`, and `1`. In order to achieve what you want, you can use a `[ValidateSet]` attribute:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet($null, $true, $false)]
    [object] $ThisValue
)
```

As a side-note, there used to be a bug with powershell (might still be present) where comparing `$null` on the right side will cause nothing to be returned, causing logic to fall out of the statement, so it's best to compare on the left:

```
if ($null -eq $ThisValue) {
```

---

After testing your example, I was unable to replicate your problem, however:

```
function Test-Nullable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [nullable[bool]] $Value
    )

    if ($null -eq $Value) {
        'Yes'
    } else {
        $Value
    }
}
```

and in array format:

```
function Test-Nullable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [nullable[bool][]] $Value
    )

    foreach ($bool in $Value) {
        if ($null -eq $bool) {
            'Yes'
        } else {
            $bool
        }
    }
}

Test-Nullable 5, 3, $null, $true, $false, 0
True
True
Yes
True
False
False
```

Comment: My problem is not with standard nullable bool but with list of bools that I need to be nullable.

Comment: @MadBoy look at my last example. It solves your problem.

Comment: Nice. If it works thats great news! On mobile now so cant test.

Comment: @MadBoy The problem was your syntax.  `Nullable<bool>` is your type and array indication goes after the type so you end up with `Nullable<bool>[]` or in powershell: `[nullable[bool][]]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried [nullable[bool[]] and it wasn't working... I see where I made mistake and it makes so much sense :-) Been banging my head for few hours yesterday / today wondering how to overcome this. You saved my PSWriteWord (https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteWord) project ;-)

Comment: Btw... the if ($null -eq $ThisValue) { is not actually a bug. I reported this once https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1021 and got a nice explanation behind it.

Comment: @MadBoy That's a completely different issue.  There used to be (still is?) a bug with powershell `$null` comparisons where nothing will be returned from the `-eq` operator and it will fall through logic constructs.

Comment: I see. Thought you mean the left vs right $null comparison.

Comment: @MadBoy Yeah... took a while to learn before upgrading to 5.1 everywhere.  I'd have if cases checking for registry keys or something but it'd skip the entire if/else blocks.  After that it just became habit.

Comment: I can imagine trying to figure it out why things are not working :-D